# Carousel transitioning affects footer links?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm at a lost with this one and was wondering if anyone else has had this issue before?

If you scroll to the bottom, you'll see the carousel I'm talking about and if you wait till it transitions, or click on one of the indicators, it'll cause the links in the footer to become active temporarily.

http://libre.colonization.co/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to your `carousel-inner` to force hardware acceleration.

```
.carousel-inner {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
          transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that actually worked. I've been going crazy trying to fix it!